# Xamarin Forms iOS. Change Back Button

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, navigationcontroller

I am trying to use the sample code mentioned at https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_back_button/ to properly customize the back button in my Xamarin Forms project (I am using Master Detail Page) but I do not know exactly where I should put those lines in my code.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Where have you tried to put those lines of code?

Comment: Nowhere. I have no idea where to put them. I know that I must put them inside the iOS solution, but I do not know where. Maybe should I create a custom renderer?

Comment: Have you tried to put them in the .cs file of the master detail page?

Comment: I think that you can put them at the end of the OnCreate method.

Comment: The code contained in the link is relative to iOS. The Master Detail Page code is in the Portable solution, I can not add them inside that class

Comment: I understand. I need to do more research then.